# Import-csv Target cell on Csv

Tags: powershell

I have a csv with a list of usernames

I want to import just one cell of the csv file  e.g.  A2

Is it possible to be that specific?   I have tried googling for this but don't see an exact solution. Tried powershell help also.

Can this be done ?

Thanks

Confuseis

Answer (score 2):

When you use Import-Csv you convert the content into a PSCustomObject.

Examples on the following table:

```
PS> $csv = Import-Csv .\test.csv
PS> $csv

ProcessName     Id    WS        CPU
-----------     --    --        ---
sihost          5996  30015488  44.640625
pia_nw          11064 10620928  52.921875
pia_nw          2344  7933952   104.0625
RuntimeBroker   6500  77500416  177.34375
SettingSyncHost 6736  5074944   202.796875
explorer        6600  284934144 272.140625
ipoint          920   3162112   372.78125
rubyw           10648 18026496  389.46875
pia_nw          3108  31330304  1640.5625
OneDrive        10208 33206272  6422.4375
```

So you will need a NoteProperty name to call a value you're looking for.

```
PS> $csv.ProcessName[0]
sihost
```

Another way is to make a header array and use that to slice the data.

If working with a an object:

```
PS> $header = ($csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInfo)[0] -replace '"' -split ",";
>>
PS> $header
ProcessName
Id
WS
CPU
```

Or if working with the file:

```
PS> $header = (gc .\test.csv)[0] -replace '"' -split ',';
ProcessName
Id
WS
CPU
```

Then just use the appropriate index:

```
PS> $csv[0]."$($header[0])"
sihost
```

Finally there is the Excel.Application ComObject method on an xlsx file. This will let you select cell's and ranges.

```
PS> $file = "C:\Some\Path\IMade\Up\test.xlsx"
PS> $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
PS> $objExcel.Visible = $false
PS> $wb = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
PS> $ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)
PS> $ws.Range("A2").Text
sihost
```

More info on using the ComObjects can be found here:
[Application Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx)

Comment: Thats very helpful, Much easier thatn I thought it would be Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The below example will select and output only 'cell' A2 from test.csv

In this example, the column header for row A is 'username'

```
$inFile = Import-Csv c:\Temp\test.csv
$targetCell = $inFile.username[1]
Write-Output $targetCell
```

This snippet is doing the following:

1. Import the csv file, yielding a PowerShell object.
2. Select the column you want to work with, the items from that column can be treated as an array.  Select the desired item in that column by referring to it's zero based index value.
3. Output the results.

Comment: You put the index on the username property, not the array.  `$inFile[1].username`

Comment: Actually, either way works.  $infile.username[1] or $infile[1].username give the same value.

Answer (score 1):

`Import-CSV` creates an array of objects from the input file.  The column labels in the first row of the CSV become the property names.  The other rows are objects in the array.  Like any array you can call one element using brackets.

```
$arrUsers = Import-CSV c:\temp\users.csv
$arrUsers[1]
```

The second command, above, prints the second object, since counting starts with 0.  This object came from the third line of the CSV file, since the first was used as column headers.

If you use `Get-Member`, it will show you the members (properties and methods) of an object.

```
$arrUsers | Get-Member
```

Assuming one of the members is `username`, combine this with array indexing, you can use:

```
$arrUsers[1].username
```

`Import-CSV` is a very flexible tool.  Especially combined with `Foreach` and `Export-CSV`.  Between `Get-Help` and `Get-Member`, you can explore Powershell with ease.  Good luck.

Comment: Thats perfect Thanks